# How to count distinct elements from different tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

this is table_1

```
d1
--------
a  
b  
c  
d  
e
```

table_2

```
d2
--------
a  
b  
d
```

table_3

```
d3
--------
b  
c
```

Expected new table which is sum of count of a,b,c,d,e from all tables above

final_table

```
a   2  
b   3  
c   2  
d   2  
e   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a simple union of the tables and a count like so

```
select id, count(id)
from(
  select id from d1
  union all
  select id from d2
  union all
  select id from d3
) t
group by id
```

[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e51771/1)

Comment: thankyou so much. i have been trying to do this for so long time.... God bless you!